# Run time permission not working from API Level 28

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I am using this  code to ask permission for CALL_PHONE, it is working below api level 28, but not working above that. Below api level 28 if the permission is not granted it is showing the dialog for giving permission, but above 28 no dialog is popping up, I am getting only the toast message.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProcessingCallActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // Permission is not granted
                                    finish();
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( ProcessingCallActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},REQUEST_PHONE_CALL);
                                    Toast.makeText(ProcessingCallActivity.this, "Call permission needed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below permission in manifest

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Remove that finish() Statement

Comment: Sure man I added the permission already. And sorry removing finish() statement did not worked.

Comment: what is your using  fragment or activity ?

Comment: check your targetSdkVersion 28 and  compileSdkVersion 28

Comment: It is activity. and the both target & compile Sdk Version is 28.